# Shell script error (: not found [No such file or directory])

Tags: bash, shell-script, windows, newlines

I'm using following script on linux server. And which is giving:

```
: not found [No such file or directory]
```

This is the script:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# K.Sugunan Host health check
#           Description
#
#           This script to initiate health check on servers.
#           It will check for CPU, memory and some connectivity with 
#           up stream and down stream system.
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------

# Applying initial variables and loading config parameters
DOCROOT=$(pwd)"/"
TIME_NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

echo $DOCROOT

. $DOCROOT"config/main.sh"
. $DOCROOT"config/web.sh"
. $DOCROOT"config/telnet.sh"

echo $CPU_A
```

The error will be like follows:

```
: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/sugunan/phobos/
: not found [No such file or directory]
: cannot open [No such file or directory]os/
```

I use following ways to run the script

```
ksh poc.sh
sh poc.sh
./poc.sh
```

All of the above giving similar error. Even I include `#!/bin/bash` still the error exist. I have tried `#!/bin/ksh` and `#!/usr/bin/ksh` also. All of that gives the error. What may be the reason for the issue on this server?

Comment: Just add at the beginning of your script `set -x` (and better add back the `#!/bin/sh` at the real beginning). This little command (I think it works also for ksh, for sure with bash) will display what it will execute and then display the execution output (if any). It is really handy to spot any mistakes. You might have to add it to your other scripts if the error comes from one of them.

Comment: Add `#!/bin/bash` as first line and start script this way: `./poc.sh`

Answer (score 7):

It appears like the empty lines contain an invisible (unprintable) character, and the server is trying to run it as if it were the name of a command; hence the error `: not found [No such file or directory]`. Delete the empty lines or ensure they're really empty.

Edit: OP's comment confirms that it is indeed the case, as the code was written under Windows. On Windows, ASCII text files end each line with a Line Feed + Carriage Return character, while UNIX uses only a Line Feed.

To solve this, you can either:

- copy & paste the code directly on an editor under Linux
- make sure you set your Windows editor to convert end-of-line characters to the UNIX standard
- use the `dos2unix` command to convert the Windows ASCII file to a UNIX one

Comment: high probability that the script file contains `\r\n` line endings.

Comment: You are correct. I use notepad++ on windows to edit the code. Which make the issue. Now I copy the code and place on linux vi editor. Thanks for suggestion. "dr01" may edit the answer accordingly. Then can mark as correct answer.

Comment: Answer edited to add a bit more info.